# How would one prove that for all positive real $a$ and $b$, $\sqrt{a+b} \neq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$?

Tags: proof-writing, radicals

I think that the best way to prove this would be to prove by contradiction. Am I right?

If so, can I just assume that $\sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ and say $a = 1$ and $b = 1$ and show that $\sqrt{1+1} \neq \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1}$, or is that not enough?

Comment: Of course, that is not enough. You have to show it for all $a,b$.

Comment: Thought so. What approach should I take? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Use proof by contradiction, or in Latin "reductio ad absurdum".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

$\sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt a + \sqrt b, \tag 1$

then, squaring,

$a + b = a + 2\sqrt a \sqrt b + b, \tag 2$

whence

$2\sqrt a \sqrt b = 0, \tag 3$

which forces

$a = 0 \vee b = 0. \tag 4$

Contradiction!

Comment: Thank you. This is the most detailed answer.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN:  my pleasure sir, thank you!

Comment: That is not a contradiction. We have not supposed that $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$

Comment: @HeMan:  $a$ and $b$ are stipulated positive in the title!

Comment: My deepest apology. You are right.

Comment: I think it would have been good specify the flaw in the reasoning in the question and say it's a better proof if you derive a contradiction using only the assumptions that a and b and positive and not using a assumptions that a and b are 1. I know you did it that way. You just didn't specify that that way and not the other way is the way to do it. I guess the author figured out from the answer that the way to do it is do derive the contradiction without the assumptions that a and b are 1 because this answer has a check mark beside it. You also missed saying that really to derive the

Comment: contradiction in the assumption that for some positive real numbers a and b, $\sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$, you need to assume that a and b are both positive. However, from your answer, I can figure out how to interpret it as a proper correct proof like that so I upvoted it anyway.

Comment: @Timothy:  as far as specifically stating in my answer that $a, b > 0$,, I wrote out of the context set by the question itself.  That being said, thank you for your remarks and your edorsement of my answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis The title of the question said something like for any positive real numbers a and b but you didn't make the assumption in your answer that a and b were positive.

Answer (score 1):

Supose that there is an equality and that $ab\neq 0$. Then square both sides. Then conclude when you obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that exist $a,b>0$ such that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$

Then $(a+b)=a+b+2\sqrt{ab} \Rightarrow \sqrt{ab}=0 \Rightarrow a=0 \text{  or  } b=0$ which is a contradiction.

Because both $a,b$ are assumed to be positive.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Answer (score 1):

if $\sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt a + \sqrt b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R^{\geq 0}}$, then $a+b = a + 2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} + b$, then $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = 0$. So $a =0$ or $b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R^+$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$. Squaring both sides we get $$a+b = a+b+2\sqrt{ab}$$
$$\implies 2\sqrt{ab}=0 \implies ab=0$$ a contradiction as $a,b \neq 0$. Therefore $\sqrt{a+b} \neq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ anytime $a$ and $b$ are nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

If it's true then it should be true for 
$$a=b=1,$$
which gives $$\sqrt2=2,$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

a,b positive real numbers.

Let $x^2:= a$, $y^2:=b,$  $x,y \gt 0.$

Consider a right triangle with lengths of legs $x,y$,

length of hypotenuse is $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.$

Sum of $2$ sides in a triangle is greater than the third side.
(Euclid)

$\Rightarrow:$

$(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \lt x + y$,

or reverting to $a,b:$

$(a+b)^{1/2} \lt a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}.$